# Django Filter QuerySet on List Using AND

Tags: python, django, filter

I'm trying to user Django's .filter() method with a list of related child objects to return the parent object set that contains all of the child records. See example below.

User is the parent object and Color is the child object directly related to User

- User1 has colors `[red, blue]`
- User2 has colors `[black, purple, green, blue]`
- User3 has colors `[red, blue, green]`
- User4 has colors `[red, blue, green, white]`

`users = users.filter(user_colors__color__in=colors)`

colors is a list set by the POST. E.g. `[red, blue, green]`

Currently, users contains the set of users which have any of `[red, blue, green]`. For the sample set above, I am currently getting `User1`, `User2`, `User3` and `User4` with the code above. I.e. it's using an OR search. I want to return only the users which have ALL of the specified colors. I.e. use an AND search. For the example above, I want to only get `User3` and `User4`.

What is the best way to get only the set of parent records (users) that have all of the requested child records (colors)? Is there a Django method that can do this easily? Or do I need to a loop that filters on each color?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you read up on Django queryset API [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: Please post your models so that we can see how the relationship is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple for loop will suffice:

```
# list of color instances
colors = [red, green, blue]

for x in colors:
    users = users.filter(user_colors__color=x)
```

Successive filters will operate as an AND

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you get your list of colors from somewhere else which I'm guessing is the case:

```
from django.db.models import Q

# list of color instances
colors = [red, green, blue]

# create a list Q filters dynamically 
filter_by_this = [Q(user_colors__color=color) for color in colors]

# filter using the filter as a list of arguments
users = users.filter(*filter_by_this)
```

This is not tested, but I believe that it should be something like that.

In any case you should read up on filtering using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects).

Comment: You can actually just use `__in` for or instead of this.

Comment: OP needs "&" not "or"